# Unable to configure textvaraible for Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a program and part of it was:

```
ent = Entry(root)
```

and then later:

```
ent.config(textvarible=a)
```

(a is a number)
When I load the program the entry is not changed. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry widgets don't work that way (Labels do). To set the value in an entry wdiget you need to delete the current contents and insert the new contents:

```
ent.delete(0, 'end')
ent.insert(0, a)
```

There is a second way of doing this. You could bind the value of the Entry to a StringVar, and then the Entry will display whatever the StringVar is set to.

```
var = StringVar(root)
ent = Entry(root, textvariable=var)

# to update: 
var.set(a)
```

Also, with this method the StringVar reflects all changes the user makes to the Entry, so you need to deal with `var` only.